# Bokeh YearsTicker and still month on the ticker sometimes

Tags: django, bokeh

I am using Bokeh for some charts in a Django project. For instance:
[![This one is fine, showing YYYY on the x axis.][1]
However, when I restrict the period of time to display (thanks to a DateRangeSlider), years are then displayed as "1/YYYY"
[![This one is bad][2]][2]

Axis are defined as follows:

```
plot.yaxis.formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="€0,0")
plot.xaxis[0].formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(years="%Y")
plot.xaxis[0].ticker = YearsTicker()
```

Has anyone a clue of how to always have tickers as YYYY?

Thanks in advance
Richard
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9vq4.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9CBp.png

Comment: This is a dupe of the other question. A `DatetimeFormatter` specifies a format for several different scales, and will switch between them as the range start/end changes. You'll need to set more of the scale formats than just `years` if you want that format to show at different scales (e.g. zooming in wuold move into `months` scale)